# Passing custom HashMap between activities in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, hashmap

I have a HashMap which takes in a String ID(ID of a chatroom) as a key and stores all the chats from that specific room in an arraylist as follow:

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<ChatMessage>> chatHistoryHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ChatMessage>>();
```

This is created in RoomActivity and I want to pass it to ChatActivity. How am I able to do this? I tried to make it a public static but using the "put" method in ChatActivity seems to do nothing, not sure why.

I also need this HashMap to be passed back to RoomActivity when the back button is pressed in ChatActivity.

Do I need to use Intents?

Comment: There is no reason for it not to work if it's static! Could you show us the code? How did it look like when u made it static. Not just the init.

Comment: Passing not parsing @MarkKeen, and if you want to just serialize it you still have to pass it.

Comment: I made it static and I could use it but the values never got changed in the ChatActivity class, many people seem to have this issue but I can't get the solution...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226336/public-static-hashmap-clear-and-put-not-work-properly

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373115/static-hashmap-not-working

Answer (score 0):

When you made anything static in your class then that variable is visible to all classes in that package so it cannot happen that you are not able to get the value in another activity.

To access the static variable you can either make th object of the class or you can directly access it by using function name.

You can also pass the object using intent.putExtra() and intent.getExtra()

Comment: Static does not make it available to other classes in the package. You can have a private static variable that can only be accessed in that class.

Comment: I made it static and I could use it but the values never got changed in the ChatActivity class, many people seem to have this issue but I can't get the solution...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226336/public-static-hashmap-clear-and-put-not-work-properly

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373115/static-hashmap-not-working